# Converting from arrays to pointers. Am I missing something?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I had to rewrite two functions as per two exercises in a book I'm working from. One that simply reads a line of characters, `readLine` and another that compared two character strings and returned either 1 or 0 based on whether they match, 'equalStrings`.

The point of the exercise was to rewrite the functions so they used pointers, as opposed to arrays.

I've been struggling with prior exercises and was surprised how quickly I was able to do this so I'm concerned I'm missing something important.

Both programs compile and run as hoped though.

This is the original `readLine` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void readLine(char buffer[]);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char line[81];

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        readLine(line);
        printf("%s\n\n", line);
    }

    return 0;
}

void readLine(char buffer[])
{
    char character;
    int i = 0;

    do
    {
        character = getchar();
        buffer[i] = character;
        i++;
    }

    while(character != '\n');

    buffer[i - 1] = '\0';
}
```

My edited with pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void readLine(char *buffer);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char line[81];
    char *pointer; 
    pointer = line;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        readLine(pointer);
        printf("%s\n\n", line);
    }

    return 0;
}

void readLine(char *buffer)
{
    char character;
    int i;
    i = 0;
    do
    {
        character = getchar();
        buffer[i] = character;
        i++;
    }

    while(character != '\n');

    buffer[i - 1] = '\0';
}
```

Here is the original equalString function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool equalStrings(const char s1[], const char s2[]);

int main(void)
{
    const char stra[] = "string compare test";
    const char strb[] = "string";

    printf("%i\n", equalStrings(stra, strb));

    printf("%i\n", equalStrings(stra, stra));
    printf("%i\n", equalStrings(strb, "string"));

    return 0;
}

bool equalStrings(const char s1[], const char s2[])
{
    int i = 0;
    bool areEqual;

    while(s1[i] == s2[i] && s1[i] != '\0'){
        i++;

        if(s1[i] == '\0' && s2[i] == '\0')
            areEqual = true;
        else
            areEqual = false;
    }
    return areEqual;
}
```

and the rewritten with pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool equalStrings(const char *pointera, const char *pointerb);

int main(void)
{
    const char stra[] = "string compare test";
    const char strb[] = "string";
    const char *pointera;
    const char *pointerb;
    pointera = stra;
    pointerb = strb;

    printf("%i\n", equalStrings(pointera, pointerb));

    printf("%i\n", equalStrings(pointerb, pointerb));
    printf("%i\n", equalStrings(strb, "string"));

    return 0;
}

bool equalStrings(const char *pointera, const char *pointerb)
{
    int i = 0;

    bool areEqual;

    while(pointera[i] == pointerb[i] && pointera[i] != '\0'){
        i++;

        if(pointera[i] == '\0' && pointerb[i] == '\0')
            areEqual = true;
        else
            areEqual = false;
    }
    return areEqual;
}
```

Is there anything glaring out that needs to be changed?

Thank you.

Comment: It may depend on your judge. For example, he/she may hate array subscripting operator `[]`.

Comment: *undefined behavior* will be invoked when zero-length string is passed for `pointera` or `s1` of `equalStrings()` and its return value is used because value of uninitialized variable `areEqual` having automatic storage duration will be used then. The same *undefined behavior* will be invoked when the first character of the two passed strings is different.

Comment: `void readLine(char buffer[]);` and `void readLine(char *buffer);` have the same meaning. (first `buffer` means a pointer rather than an array)

Comment: I only read readLine code. You can reconsider assigning array to char*. You can directly read the input in char* so why need to have an char[].

Comment: You're still using char arrays inside the rewritten functions. Why not doing the exercise deeply and also use pointers inside them ?

Comment: `s1` and `s2` in the original function are already pointers (array parameters/arguments are always converted to pointers). I am assuming the exercise rather is about using pointer *syntax*, so try using `pointera++` instead of `i++` and `*pointera` instead of `pointera[i]`.

Comment: Exercise 10.10, in Kochan's Programming In C 4th ed., calls for rewriting the compareStrings() function from chapter 9 so that pointers are used instead of arrays. Your starting with a different function from chapter 9, equalStrings(), instead.

Comment: ahhh goddamnit, very similar but you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (3) conditions you need to protect against in your `readline` function. (1) you must protect against writing beyond the end of your array. Utilizing a simple counter to keep track of the number of characters added will suffice. You can express this limit in your read loop. Your array size is `81` (which will hold a string of `80` characters `+1` for the *nul-terminating* character. Assuming you create a `#define MAXC 81` for use in your code, your first condition could be written as:

```
void readline (char *buffer)
{
    int i = 0, c;
    while (i + 1 < MAXC && ...
```

(2) the second condition you want to protect against is reaching a `'\n'` newline character. The second condition for your read loop could be written as:

```
    while (i + 1 < MAXC && (c = getchar()) != '\n' && ...
```

(3) the third condition you must protect against is encountering `EOF` with a line before a newline character is reached (many editors produce files with non-POSIX line-endings). With the final condition, your complete set of test conditions could look like the following:

```
    while (i + 1 < MAXC && (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
```

(and that is why `c` must be *signed* (and should be a signed `int`), because `EOF` is generally `-1`)

Putting that together, with what it appears was intended in rewriting the function from using *array-index* notation to using *pointer* notation, you could do something like the following:

```
void readline (char *buffer)
{
    int i = 0, c;

    while (i + 1 < MAXC && (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        *buffer++ = c;
        i++;
    }
    *buffer = 0;

    if (i + 1 == MAXC && *(buffer - 1) != '\n')
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: line truncation occurred.\n");
}
```

You should also check, as shown above, whether you read all the characters in the line, or whether a *short-read* occurred (meaning after reading `80` allowable characters, there were still more characters in the line to be read, but to prevent writing beyond the end of your array, and leaving room for the terminating nul, you stopped reading before your reached the newline). You are free to handle it as you like, but be aware -- those characters still exist in the *input buffer* (`stdin` here) and will be the very next characters read on your next call to `getchar()`. So you may want a way to tell if that occurred.

Putting the function together in a short example with a helpful input file will help explain.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 81

void readline(char *buffer);

int main(void) {

    int i;
    char line[MAXC] = "", *pointer = line;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        readline (pointer);
        printf ("%s\n\n", line);
    }

    return 0;
}

void readline (char *buffer)
{
    int i = 0, c;

    while (i + 1 < MAXC && (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        *buffer++ = c;
        i++;
    }
    *buffer = 0;

    if (i + 1 == MAXC && *(buffer - 1) != '\n')
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: line truncation occurred.\n");
}
```

How will your function behave if given a `90` character line to read?

**Input File**

Two lines with 90 characters each.

```
$cat dat/90.txt
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```

**Example Use/Output**

Note what has occurred. On the first read attempt, `80` character were read, and a *short read* occurred. You were warned of that fact. The second read, read the reamining `10` characters in the first line (chars `81-90`). The third, and final, read, again reads the first `80` chars of the second line and the code terminates.

```
$ ./bin/getchar_ptr <dat/90.txt
warning: line truncation occurred.
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890

1234567890

warning: line truncation occurred.
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```

I'll let you look this over and incorporate any of the suggestions you find helpul in the rest of your code. Let me know if you have any questions. Make sure you fully undetstand what is being passed as `buffer` in `void readline (char *buffer)` (copy as opposed to original) as basic pointer understandin has implications throughout C.

Comment: Thank you for explaining all of this, David. This is very helpful.

I'm a little confused where within the readLine function that GetChar() is called. Is it inside the actual while condition? :S

Comment: Yes, you are free to move it out of the *test* clause of the `while` loop if you want, but I always found it convenient to put the actual loop tests in the `while` test clause (as long as it made sense to do it). Each of the three tests I explain are all present in the `while (a && b && c)` with the `b` test being `(c = getchar()) != '\n'` which calls `getchar()` and assigns the character returned to `c` (which is all inside a set of parenthesis `(...)` to allow the assignment. Then the value `c` inside the `(...)` is checked against newline, e.g. `(...) != '\n'`.